# Can i send textarea with file using Ajax for php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i want to send multiple inputs and textarea with file using ajax to php page , but i will get textarea box is empty

here is my html code

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizantal" id="posts_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
<input type='email' name='email' id='email'>
<textarea id='kind' name='kind'></textarea>
<input value='save' id='btn-save' type='button' class='button'>
</form>
```

and here is javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-save").click(function () {
        $("#posts_form").submit();
    });
    $("#posts_form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'procces.php?action=save_post',
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            async: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                msg.html("<img src='../icon/default/loading.gif' class='img-responsive' width='10%'>");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                //success
                } else {
                //error
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: shouldnt the `data` be `data : new FormData($(this)[0]),` ?

Comment: Show us the php side

Comment: i'll tried it data : new FormData($(this)[0]), but not fixed

Comment: this is my error [object HTMLTextAreaElement]